# How can I disable the "wrong way" timer?

Tags: cheats, need-for-speed-shift-2-unleashed

I like to crash in car games in offline mode :)

Is it possible to disable the "wrong way" timer with a mod or trainer? I want to crash into cars head-on by driving backwards.

I can't find this answer anywhere online. You can probably edit and repack some .bff files to disable it, but I'm not sure what to do exactly.

Any ideas / suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I created a cheat to do this using the [cheat engine](https://cheatengine.org/).

**TL;DR**
For shift1 replace memory at `004BDE30` with `ret 0008`
For shift2 replace memory at `00551550` with `ret 0008`

## WARNING! This is a hack. If you do not follow these instructions exactly it could corrupt your save game OR WORSE! It may break something even if you do follow them to the letter. Use at your own risk.

Now with the big scary warning out of the way. This hack seems pretty stable and the worst that I've experienced is that the game crashes. In that case I just rebooted the game and everything was fine.

This hack only works for the **steam versions** of nfs shift 1 and shift 2 unleashed. The procedure for applying this hack for either game goes something like this.

1. Launch either game and then open the cheat engine.
2. In cheat engine click on 'select a process to open' (the computer icon in the top left under File) -> Select the game executable in the Applications tab -> Open -> click on Memory View -> right click on any address in the memory viewer -> click 'Go to address' in the menu that pops up -> for shift1 type in `004BDE30` for shift2 type in `00551550` -> ok.
3. Now you should see the Opcode 'push ebp' highlighted (this will be the same for both shift1 and shift2). If you do not see this then don't proceed or else you might break something e.g. corrupt your game save.
4. Right click on that Opcode -> click assemble -> for either game type in `ret 0008`
5. To undo the hack just reboot the game.

Now you should be able to drive backwards in the shift games. Have fun with the carnage :D

### How does this hack work?

This hack disables a function from being able to run and I *think* this function checks to see if you're driving backwards, and has some logic to determine if it should disqualify you. If it never runs you can't be disqualified for driving backwards. You can still get disqualified if you cut too many corners though.